# Como conectar uma página HTML, usando ASP, no banco SQL Server?

Tags: html, sql-server, asp

Como faço para conectar um banco de dados sql num site html usando asp?

**Observação:** Já possuo o banco inteiro desenvolvido e a página inteira também, só preciso saber como faço essa ponte entre os dois

Comment: Eu utilizo o JSON e recomendo. 1) Crie um página de conexão com o banco de dados com asp clássico[ conn.asp ]; 2) Crie um arquivo asp contendo código para gerar JSON[ arquivo_json.asp ]; 3) Coloque o conn.asp como include na página arquivo_json.asp; 4) Utilize JQUERY para recuperar as informações do arquivo_json.asp e colocar aonde deseja na página HTML. No meu site eu faço um passo a passo veja lá [ http://programano.marsites.com.br/?p=67 ]

Comment: olá, acesse este site acho que vai te ajudar http://programano.marsites.com.br/?p=67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gui Sartori, é bom colocar alguns detalhes que fazem a diferença tipo:

- É asp classico ou asp.net
- O SQL qual é a versão 2008, 2012

Se for asp classico segue

```
'<% 

    Dim conexao, stringConexao, host, usuario, senha, banco 
    host   ="SERVIDOR"
    usuario="BASE" 
    senha  ="SENHA"
    banco  ="BANCO"

    Monta a string de conexão utilizando os dados informados anteriormente
    stringConexao ="Provider=SQLNCLI10;
    SERVER="&host&";DATABASE="&banco&";UID="&usuario&";PWD="&senha&";"

  ##Instancia o objeto de conexão com o banco
  SET conexao = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

  On Error Resume Next

 ##Abre a conexão junto ao banco
 conexao.Open stringConexao

##Tratamento de erro. Caso ocorra problemas na conexão, exibe esta informação e apresenta detalhes.
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    response.write "<b><font color='red'>Conexão com o banco'"&banco&"'Microsoft SQL Server falhou !</font></b>"
   response.write "<BR><BR>"
   response.write "<b>Erro.Description:</b> " & Err.Description & "<br>"
   response.write "<b>Erro.Number:</b> " & Err.Number & "<br>"
   response.write "<b>Erro.Source:</b> " & Err.Source & "<br>"
Else
   ##Caso a conexão seja bem sucedida, mostra mensagem de confirmação.
     response.write "<b><font color='blue'> Conexão com o banco '" & banco & "' Microsoft SQL Server estabelecida com sucesso !</font>"
End If

 ##Fecha a conexão com o banco
 conexao.close

 ##Remove as referência do objeto da memória
 SET conexao = Nothing
 %>
```

Não sei asp classico vi esse codigo na wiki da locaweb [acesse aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Conectando-se_ao_MS_SQL_Server_atrav%C3%A9s_do_Asp)

Answer (score 2):

Há diversas maneiras de solucionar o seu problema.
Eu utilizaria o entity framework para mapear meus objetos do banco em classes (database-first) e inserir a minha conectionstring no config. Após isto, no seu controller (caso seja MVC), referencie a conexão do banco e execute a consulta necessária guardando os resultados em uma lista<>. Envie a lista do controller pra view via viewmodel..

Ex. controller:
private ProdutosContext bancodedados = new ProdutosContext ();

List produtos = new List
produtos = bancodedados.Produtos.ToList();

*necessário criar uma classe Produtos() com suas propriedades, exemplo: ProdutoID, Nome, Descricao, Preco {get;set;} etc..

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller

Recomendo você ler esses dois artigos.